How to run "sudo su - group_account" and then run BASH
how can I run these commands via Ansible:
manual commands:
[alpha_user@host_lon_01 ~]$sudo su - beta_user  
$bash   
[beta_user@host_lon_01 ~]$  
[beta_user@host_lon_01 ~]$ touch *

I am having issues switching the user, we dont have to put any passwords or anything, just a simple switch using sudo su - beta_user.
and then we have to run bash, makes it easier to use tabs etc.
can anyone help on this please
I tried different "become" techniques in playbooks but its not switching the user

Why would you want to do that in the first place? sudo -u beta_user bash -c 'touch *' is far simpler. sudo su - is redundant and pointless -- sudo itself can directly start a shell without needing su (see in particular sudo -u beta_user -l)

Similarly, if you want an interactive login shell where you don't honor the target account's configuration to select that shell, sudo -u beta_user bash -il; no su needed.

But insofar as this is about interactive use instead of software development it's off-topic here altogether. You probably want [unix.se]

"How can I run these commands via Ansible?", you don't need to. If you want to touch files you can just use file module – Manage files and file properties. "I tried different "become" techniques in playbooks but its not switching the user", that's documented under Understanding privilege escalation: become, answered here on SO several times, and without any further information and error not answerable.

Actually im not trying to touch, its an example command..i have to run a script, which we manually run by first switching the user by "sudo su - beta_user" and then executing it.
If I try any other way of switching user, it asks for a password which we dont have by security policy.
We use "su" and not just "u"
please suggest something.

You can use become_user: beta_user as in this example:
- name: Example
  hosts: all:!localhost
  become: true
  become_user: beta_user
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

    - name: Touch a file
      ansible.builtin.file:
        path: ~/myfile
        state: touch
        mode: '0640'

You'd run the playbook with --ask-become-pass and fill in the sudo password of the ansible_user (the one used to connect).
